# Checking Boolean Algebra work - Simplification

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra

I am currently working on an assignment for a CE class I am taking, and I wanted to know if I have been simplifying these equations correctly. I'm supposed to reduce them to a sum of products.

1) $(A+B)(C+B)(D’+B)(ACD’+E)$

$AC + AB +AD'+AB+AACD'+AE+CB+BB+D'B+BB+ACD'B + BE  $ 
$AC + AB + AD' + ACD' + AE + CB + B + ACD'B + D'B + BE$
$AC + AB + AD' + ACD' + AE + CB + B + D'B + BE$
$AC + AB + AD' + AE + CB + B + D'B + BE  $
$A(C + B + D' + E) + B(C + D' + E + B)$
$AC + AB + AD' + AE + B $ 
$AC + AD' + AE +  B$

2). $(A’+B+C’)(A’+C’+D)(B’+D’)$

$A'A' + A'C' + A'D + A'B' + A'D' + A'B + BC' + BD + B'B + BD' + A'C' + C'C' + C'D + B'C'+ C'D' $
$A' + A'C' + A'D + A'B' + A'D' + A'B + BC' + BD + B'B + BD'  + C' + C'D + B'C' + C'D' $
$A' + A'C + A' + A' + C' + B + B'B + C' + C' $
$A' + A' + A' + C' + B + B'B + C' + C'$
$A' + C' + B + B'B  $
$A' + C' + B  $

3). $ [(AB’)+C’D]’ $

$(AB')' (C'D)'   $
$(A'+B)(C+D')   $
$A'C + A'D' + CB + BD' $

4). $ [A+B(C’+D)]’$

$ A'B'+(C'+D)'   $
$ A'B' + CD'    $

5). $ (A  \oplus BC)+BD+ACD $

$(A'BC + AB'C') + BD + ACD $
$A'BC + AB'C' + BD + ACD  $
$A'B + A'C + AB'C' + BD +  ACD $

Comment: Improve the formatting like this

Comment: I fixed the formatting. I tried to fix XOR, but I don't know how to insert the XOR symbol.

Comment: use this \oplus for $\oplus$ and \veebar for $\veebar$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for 1)
$$\begin{align}
& (A+B)(C+B)(D'+B)(ACD'+E) \\
& (AC+B)(ACD'+D'E+BE) \\
& (ACD'+BE)
\end{align}$$
Rather than multiplying out everything and simplifying at the end, I have simplified
intermediate factors to reduce the length of my calculation.

Simplification rules:
$$x + x = x$$
$$x + xy = x$$
$$x x = x$$
$$x x' = \text{false}$$
$$x + x' = \text{true}$$
$$x + x'y = x + y$$

It helps to keep factor literals in alphabetical order.

My solution for 2)
$$\begin{align}
& (A'+B+C')(A'+C'+D)(B'+D') \\
& (A'+BD+C')(B'+D') \\
& (A'B'+A'D'+B'C'+C'D')
\end{align}$$

My solution for 3)
$$\begin{align}
& [(AB′)+C′D]′ \\
& (AB')'(C'D')' \\
& (A'+B)(C+D) \\
& (A'C+A'D+BC+BD)
\end{align}$$

My solution for 4)
$$\begin{align}
& [A+B(C′+D)]′ \\
& (A'(B(C'+D))') \\
& (A'(B'+(C'+D)')) \\
& (A'(B'+CD')) \\
& (A'B'+A'CD')
\end{align}$$

My solution for 5)
$$\begin{align}
& (A\oplus (BC))+BD+ACD \\
& (A'BC+A(BC)')+BD+ACD \\
& (A'BC+A(B'+C'))+BD+ACD \\
& (A'BC+AB'+AC')+BD+ACD \\
& (A'BC+AB'+AC'+BD) 
\end{align}$$

To verify the calculations, a truth table might make sense.